# How to make camera animation filters

Tags: flutter

I would like to ask you something. I want to develop a camera application and use filters to create the effects of Disney princesses and princes (as shown below). What technology do I need to learn? Currently I will use flutter.

My English is not very good, thank you all, I hope you can help me

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- If you choose flutter then it is a great choice for cross-platform
  mobile development and offers extensive support for creating custom
  UI components.
- But you need to learn about image processing techniques. This could
  involve adjusting colors, applying masks, or adding overlays.
- You also need to learn about the filter algorithms. Where you may
  need to explore various image processing techniques such as
  convolution, color transformations, edge detection, or blending
  modes. OpenCV or TensorFlow Lite might be useful for more advanced
  image processing tasks.